# how to make percentage with pivot columns using pivot in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe

```
Resolution    category    month  region
<=10days       cat1       nov    global
<=10days       cat2       nov    global
11-15days      cat1       nov    global
 >15days        cat1       nov    global
```

Now, I want to build these categories based on the column "resolution and Category":

```
 Resolution    cat1    cat2   overallcat     cat1%  cat2%  overallcat%
 <=10days       1       1      2            
  11-15days      1       0      1            
  >15days        1       0      1
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you'd formatted your text.

Comment: can any one help on this?

Comment: I believe you're question is not clear enough. For example, what do you want to have in `cat1%`?